# How to check if a value in a column is found in a list in a column, with Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a delta table A as shown below.

| point | cluster | points_in_cluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37 | 1 | [37,32] |
| 45 | 2 | [45,67,84] |
| 67 | 2 | [45,67,84] |
| 84 | 2 | [45,67,84] |
| 32 | 1 | [37,32] |

Also I have a table B as shown below.

| id | point |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 37 |
| 102 | 67 |
| 103 | 84 |

I want a query like the following. Here `in` obviously doesn't work for a list. So, what would be the right syntax?

```
select b.id, a.point
from A a, B b
where b.point in a.points_in_cluster
```

As a result I should have a table like the following

| id | point |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 37 |
| 101 | 32 |
| 102 | 45 |
| 102 | 67 |
| 102 | 84 |
| 103 | 45 |
| 103 | 67 |
| 103 | 84 |

Comment: [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#array_contains)

Comment: @Steven This works. Thanks!

Comment: added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data sample, I'd do an equi-join on `point` column and then an [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) on `points_in_cluster` :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# assuming A is df_A and B is df_B

df_A.join(
    df_B,
    on="point"
).select(
    "id",
    F.explode("points_in_cluster").alias("point")
)
```

---

Otherwise, you use [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#array_contains):

```sql
select b.id, a.point
from A a, B b
where array_contains(a.points_in_cluster, b.point)
```